# Does scaling a microservice instances directly affects database instances as well?

Tags: java, spring-boot, microservices

I am new to microservices architecture, but I have learned that a key advantage of using such architecture is **scaling**.

Say we have one microservice instance and it is connected to one Mysql database.

Now we need to **scale it up** to be 3 instances instead of one, **does that mean that each instance will have its own database**? or it will be 3 instances and one database?

Any information is appreciated.

Comment: It depends. If you tell compose to create a DB for each instance then yes. If you dont then know. This is up to your own configuration. Multiple applications can connect to a single database just like a single application can connect to multiple DB. Then you have sharing and parallel DB for redundancy and speed. We cant tell you what your own application does with no information.

Comment: Usually, a microservice has a database per service. Everything should be independent. If you have a single database instance shared, then deploying a database change could bring down all 3 instances. Ideally, you share nothing.

Answer (score 2):

Usually you would like to have a single database backing a microservice. Otherwise you are just creating multiple instances of the same service. Challenges there are to avoid locking tables and/or rows so the services scaling is worth.

Classic SQL database are hard to scale horizontally (typically the do not support multiple write replicas and depends on a single node for writing). This also represents a challenge in case your services are geographically distributed. There are multiple ways to reduce those effects (using no SQL databases, messages queues) but which matches best depends on each context.

Just in case, sharing database amongst several microservices is definitely an anti-pattern. That is using the database as integration point.